# viewWillDisappear being called when I restart my app

Tags: swift, firebase, uiviewcontroller, lifecycle

I've tested this bug extensively and narrowed it down to just a few lines of code. Having trouble understanding how the following could be happening and how to avoid it so any input is greatly appreciated. Let me know if there's any more info needed to diagnose.

I have messaging in my app and in order to determine whether or not the user has unread messages, all messages that are sent include a flag indicating that the receiving user has not yet seen them. There are two ways in which the user marks the conversation "read":

1. Tap on the conversation
2. Be in the conversation then back out of it (viewWillDisappear called)

--- I have verified that the code in viewWidllDisappear (below) is being called when I re-open the app

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
       if conversation?.lastMessageSender != currUserName && conversation?.receiverViewed == false {
        
           let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
           db.collection("conversations").document(conversationID).updateData(["receiverViewed":true])
       }
   }
```

For reference, my database is Firebase.

Reproduction Steps:

- Receive a message
- Go to conversation and view the message
- Close the app **while on the messageDetail view controller**
- Receive another message
- Open the app

**Expected**:
App opens to home screen with indication that there is an unread message. Navigating to messagesViewController shows that unread conversation

**Actual**:
App opens to home screen with NO indication of an unread message. Navigating to messagesViewController shows that the conversation has ben read

Comment: Is the `db.collection` call asynchronous?

Comment: It is asynchronous. And by the way, I have come up with a workaround of dismissing the messageDetail View Controller when the app moves to background. I am interested in understanding why this is happening and avoiding a band-aid solution.

Comment: Not to not nit-pick but if you CLOSE the app, it will not be receiving another message, right? It's closed and no code is running. Are you perhaps doing something with notifications then? Also, why would `viewWillDisappear` be called if the the app is opening? If you review the [ViewController lifecycle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller) the view will only ever disappear after it has `viewDidAppear`. Are you adding a listener to Firebase for unread messages when the app launches? If you can clarify the question, we'll take a look!

Comment: Hi @Jay, the questions you asked were my own questions and are why I did so much testing before determining that viewWillDisappear was actually running when the app was started again. As of now my push notifications are dumb and simply being sent from firebase with no actionable code. This bug even happens when I open the app by tapping on the app icon (not the notification). Yes I have a listener pulling messages down from the server. I'll give any details I can, and thank you for looking at it!

Comment: The question really needs to be updated; add a breakpoint and step through your code until you see where viewWillDisappear is being called and backtrack from there.